# stream socket and server sent event

Tags: javascript, php

again im working on some realtime system using stream_socket and on client side server sent events...as im not pro neither intelligent enough to solve case myself.

here's the thing im getting updates from one server to this using udp..and want to show data to user lively by server sent events or other without using apis or libraries. .

**php code**

```
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://127.0.0.1:7755", $errno, $errstr,STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
if (!$socket) {
die ( "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n");
} 
while (true) {
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$got= stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 1500);// just say im getting time update every 1 second from the sender
echo $got;
flush();
}


?>
```

**js part**

```
var source = new EventSource("receive.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML + =event.data + "<br>";
 };
```

Comment: EventSource is based on HTTP, not UPD. you just need a slightly modified HTTP response to use EventSource.

Comment: appreciate for comment..im trying currently what i can think of,still makes me limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Learned that php won't echo until its fully executed.** i will be trying for more option to keep connection open instead request file again. for time being this works perfectly still there are few packets missed but works.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$sock=stream_socket_server("udp://127.0.0.1:7755",$errno,$errstr,STREAM_SERVER_BIND);

if (!$sock) { 
 die("$errstr ($errno)"); 
} 

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$d=stream_socket_recvfrom($sock, 1500); 

echo "data: {$d}\n\n";

flush();
?>
```

**JS**

```
var source = new EventSource("receive.php");
 source.onmessage = function(event) {
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML + =event.data + "<br>";
};
```